# How to select similar string values from MySql?

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a table 'question' with following columns:

1. ID (primary key)
2. title (Question subject/title)
3. body (Question details)

Now say if user is asking a question, and as soon he finishes his title, I actually fire an event to get questions available similar to this title.

Now how can I am match user's input (title) to existing titles in question table and get the similar ones out?

I am using MySql Db. Please help me with this.

Comment: You can start by defining what "similar" actually means

Comment: similar how? string length? word frequence? gratuitous use of the word "belgium" in a serious database operation?

Comment: @MarcB: That's belgium ridiculous!  Who would belgium use a gratuitous belgium word in the belgium middle of serious belgium database operations?  Belgium.

Comment: 1. You should use ajax to handle the realtime request.
2. You can do an LIKE sql request to retrieve the input.

Comment: @eggyal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life,_the_Universe_and_Everything#Censorship

Comment: @MarcB - what you talking aboot?

Comment: @MarcB: Quite ;)  although, personally, I find Belgium more offensive than F*ck.

Comment: Back on topic, have you considered [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: @eggyal: *la la la la* can't hear you through this towel I've got wrapped around my head *la la la la*

Comment: @eggyal: My table is INNODB, so fulltext search is not an option.

Comment: @Arry: v5.6 supports fulltext indexes in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the Levenshtein distance?

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
    -- max strlen=255 
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256); 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN c; 
  END;
```

Helper function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END;
```

(From http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552), common mysql queries

Or you could use "LIKE" with generous wildcards, would be simpler

```
  SELECT title FROM yourTable WHERE title LIKE '%yourTitle%';
```

If you deem the body to be relevent as well,

```
  SELECT title FROm yourTable WHERE body LIKE '%yourTitle%';
```